# Limiting the records per page and the number of pages in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, reactive-programming, dynamodb-queries

I am using `DynamoDBEnchancedAsyncClient` to query `DynamoDB` using `GSI` and `pagination`. Below is the code that I am using to achieve the same. I am tying to limit the number of items per page and number of pages sent to the subscriber of the `Flux`

```
DynamoDBAsyncIndex<Customer> secindex= dynamodbasyncenhancedclient.table(Customer, Customer_Schema).index(GSI_INDEX_NAME)

SdkPublisher<Page<Customer>> query = secindex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().queryConditional(queryconditional)).limit(2).build()

Flux.from(PagePublisher.create(query).items().limit(5))
```

Few observations that I made are

The limit(2) in the `QueryEnhancedRequest` limits the number of items per page to 2. I checked it by subscribing to the `SDKPublisher`.

1. However I want to limit the pages that are sent to the subscriber of the Flux above , but `limit(5)` is not giving the desired result. Is there any way to limit the number of pages that are emitted from the above `flux`?
2. Is there any way to limit the number of pages that are fetched from the `DDB` for a particular query request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling

```
SdkPublisher<Page<Customer>> query = secindex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().queryConditional(queryconditional)).limit(2).build()
```

the `limit(2)` is being called on the `PagePublisher` being the result of `DynamoDbAsyncIndex#query` result. In order to provide the `QueryEnhancedRequest#limit` you should call the `limit` on the `QueryEnhancedRequest.Builder`:

```
secindex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().queryConditional(queryconditional).limit(2).build())
```

On the other hand, the `PagePublisher.create(query)` result will be a publisher emitting flattened items from the query result pages, i.e., emitting all pages items as a sequence of results.
To set the limit of emitted `Page`s, you should set the `limit` over the query result `SdkPublisher<Page<Customer>>`:

```
Flux.from(PagePublisher.create(query.limit(5)).items())
```

Comment: Thank you!! I know we can send the lastevaluatedkey to the client as some kind of next button, so that once client clicks it, it will be sent back and we can use it as an exclusivestartkey of the next page to retrieve the next page. But how will it be possible to send the lastevaluatedkey to the client as we are returning only items from the Page?